# How to open document file in Google docs using asp.net,c#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I just want to open my .docx, .doc, .ppt etc file in browser using google docs, i have written code to upload document in google docs, and i also written code to get the title of document,author,etc of my document which has been uploaded on google doc....

I want to open upload document(google docs)...in browser..using .net code......

here is my code to upload file

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("email@gmail.com", "password");
DocumentEntry newEntry = myService.UploadDocument(@"d:\abc.docx", "abc.docx");
}
```

here is my code to get title and other info...

```
 DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
        myService.setUserCredentials("email@gmail.com", "password");

        DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
        DocumentsFeed feed = myService.Query(query);

        Console.WriteLine("Your docs: ");
        foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            Label1.Text = entry.Title.Text;

        }
```

please suggest me... thanks in advance...

Comment: Does it really need to be opened in a browser?

Comment: yaa.. of-course. means i want to open my document without using M.S Office using google docs api

Comment: Can you get the link of the document?

Comment: i have no idea to get link of document.. through code... i have not any property to get link of doc

Comment: Hey Yakup Unyilmaz i have got url of doc... thanks for your idea...

Comment: If you got the link you can use a [LinkLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.100).aspx) in your form. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288420(v=vs.71).aspx) example from msdn to learn how to use it